Evaluation Metrics for Item-Focused Tree in Identification of Differential Item Functioning in a Real-World Data
I am working on a real-world data set comprising patient-reported outcome measures. I will apply LASSO and item-focused tree (IFT) (some machine-learning methods with Logistic regression underlying model) to detect items exhibiting DIF. I will have some trees as the result of my IFT model that show me what DIF items are and what covariates are associated with DIF. I need to evaluate the fit of the IFT model but there are no fit statistics provided by the DIFtree package in R which I need to use.
I would appreciate it if anybody knows a reference or a solution for this.
